# Content Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

День добрый, 
Изучаю понемногу JS, стал делать [слайдер,](http://jsfiddle.net/CmcE6/3/) для того чтоб практиковаться. Если у кого-то есть время, укажите где какие ошибки и какие статьи почитать по этому поводу. Спасибо.

Comment: Может вам нужно добавить функции автопрокрутки и приостановки? Вот [пример][1].


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5b9S9/6/

Comment: id не надо внутри плагина использовать, особенно так:

    ('#navs li:first').addClass('active');

потом у вас есть сеттинг:

    nav: $('li#nav'),

и далее вы почему-то пишите

    $('li#nav').bind('click', function ()

и вообще **элемент с id должен быть уникальным в документе**, т.е. li#nav низзя!

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, 
   $('li#nav').bind('click', function ()
использую потому что ul : $('li#nav') не кешируется в самом начале так как список листалки слайдера формируется динамический при его инициализации. К сожалению не совсем еще разобрался что в плагине куда можно перемещать чтобы избежать подобный неприятностей. По этому пока эксперементирую

Comment: я говорю вы нарушаете стандарт html используя множество #nav

Comment: А если такой http://codepen.io/Cone/pen/CojJf  вариант ??